# How to bind a data value to an id in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, laravel-blade

I am getting data from an array and I am binding the title in the div. Now for each title aka `key`, I have multiple cards, thus another `foreach` loop. I want to set the id as `$key`. How can I achieve that?
I think I am doing this incorrectly at present.

```
@foreach ($data as $key => $cardData)
            <div class="event-list__current-events-section">
                <div class="event-list__current-schedule">
                    <h1 class="modules-title">{{ ucwords(trans($key)) }}</h1>

                <div id="{{$key}}"> //set the id as the key here

                    @include('includes/event-card',['data'=>$cardData,'hideLoadMore'=>false,'type'=>$key])
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: id need to be unique per element. so use `class` instead

Comment: the `{{$key}}` is unique everytime. Not a single one is the same as the previous one. But for some reason this value is not found when I use this `let cardsToAppend = response.data;
   
   $(`"#`+key+`"`).append(cardsToAppend);`

Comment: I get `unrecognized expression error: '#key-name'`